# Set HTML input value with datetime-local type Laravel

Tags: php, html, datetime, laravel-4

I have been using this method for loading database data into forms:

```
value="{{$offer->name}}"
```

This method works with all other input types but not with `type="datetime-local"`
The date and time have been stored in mysql with type `datetime`.

is their any methods to get the time and date back into the field (`datetime-local`) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs at http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.value tell me you need to use the specified format: 1996-12-19T16:39:57

> The following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
> - A date.
> - The literal string "T".
> - A time.

So, you need to format the database format to the above format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_replace on your controller and send the value to the view.
Something like this:

```
$offer_name = str_replace(' ', 'T', $offer->name);
```